# Exponentially distributed induced random variable from a uniformly distributed random variable

Tags: probability

The text that I am using says that, given a continuous uniformly distributed r.v. $X\sim U(0,1)$ with a p.d.f. given by

$$ f_X(x) = \cases{1 & if $0 < x < 1$\cr
                   0 & otherwise\cr} $$

the p.d.f. $f_Y(y)$ of its induced r.v. $Y=g(X)$ where $g$ is the function $g(x) = -log_e(x)/\lambda$ for $\lambda > 0$ is going to be

$$ f_Y(y) = \cases{\lambda e^{-\lambda y} & for $y > 0$\cr
                   0 & otherwise\cr} $$ 
i.e. $Y \sim Exp(\lambda)$.

Now, I don’t really understand how $f_Y(y)$ could be defined for positive $y$. The r.v. $X : \Omega \to R_X=(0,1)$ , when composed with $g : R_X \to R_Y$ (i.e. $Y=g(X) : \Omega \to R_Y$) will only output negative values since $ -log_e(x)/\lambda$ is always negative. Therefore there shouldn’t be any $y > 0$ in the set $R_Y$, or am I wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
&0 < x < 1 \\
&\iff \log_e (x) < 0 \\
&\iff \frac{\log_e (x)}{\lambda} < 0 \\
&\iff -\frac{\log_e (x)}{\lambda} > 0 \\
\end{align}

Hence $Y$ takes positive values.